# How to suppress ActiveX warning dialogs in TEmbeddedWB?

Tags: delphi, activex, twebbrowser, delphi-xe8, tembeddedwb

In a Delphi XE8 VCL Form project using [TEmbeddedWB](https://github.com/danielfrimerman/Delphi-EmbeddedWB-XE3), in EmbeddedWB1 for security reasons I set both `DontExecuteActiveX` and `DontDownloadActiveX` properties to `True`:

[image]

I have also disabled dialog-boxes in EmbeddedWB1 by setting `EmbeddedWB1.DialogBoxes.DisableAll` to `True`:

[image]

However, when I navigate to a page like:
https://www.iplocation.net/
or:
http://www.hostip.info/
I still get ActiveX warning dialog boxes:

> One or more ActiveX controls could not be displayed because either: 1)
>   Your current security settings prohibit running ActiveX controls on
>   this page, or 2) You have blocked a publisher of one of the controls.
>   As a result, the page might not display correctly.

So how can I suppress these dialog boxes?

Comment: I am not sure if it's the same with TEmbeddedWB, but with TWebBrowser,  if you do a "Doc.DesignMode := 'on'; " on the IHtmlDocument2 interface of the document in the browser, it suppresses pop-up warnings about js errors.  Might be worth seeing if it does similar for your ActiveX warnings.  If you find that it does, I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Locate Your EmbeddedWB component -> Events -> OnScriptError:
fill these lines here:

```
continuescript:=true;
showdialog:=false;
```

It's much better that turnin on "Silent" mode, some webpages not loading correctly with "`Silent:=True`" parameter...

Hope it helps